# Reuse a component multiple times on different instances

Tags: angular, typescript

I have searched real good before publishing that question,
I found questions similar to my question but no solution was solving my problem.

I have created angular component of "styled" radio button.
I need to reuse it multiple times on a different instances.

please take a look at this image:

[image]

**How can i achieve multiple independent instance behavior?**

*A summary of the relevant parts in my code:*

> Parent component .ts file:

```
    import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
    import { TxtZoneComponent } from './txtzone/txtzone.component';
    import { EditorDirective } from './txtzone/editor.directive';
    import { RadioButtonComponent } from './CustomControls/RadioButton';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['app/App.css'],

    })
    export class AppComponent {
        public Myheader: string = "Line Breaker Web Application"
        public RadButtonBackColor: string = "rgb(50,50,50)"
        @ViewChild(EditorDirective) vc: EditorDirective;
        constructor()
        {

        }

}
```

> Parent component .html file:

```
<div><MyRadBtn [Description]="'Break Word'" [BackColor]="RadButtonBackColor">Loading...</MyRadBtn></div>
<div><MyRadBtn [Description]="'SQL Mode'" [BackColor]="RadButtonBackColor">Loading...</MyRadBtn></div>
```

> RadioButton component .ts file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
//import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
    selector: 'MyRadBtn',
    templateUrl: 'app/CustomControls/RadioButton.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/CustomControls/RadioButtonStyleSheet.css'],
})



export class RadioButtonComponent
{


    @Input() BackColor: string = "rgb(50,50,50)";
    @Input() Description: string;
    constructor()
    {

    }

    ngOnChanges() {

    }

    clicked(): void
    {
        alert(this.Description);
    }
}
```

> RadioButton .html file:

```
<div class="breakwordcont" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': BackColor}">
    <div class="desc"><span>{{Description}}</span></div>
    <div class="control">
        <div class="slideOne">
            <input type='checkbox' value='None' id='slideOne' name='check' (click)="clicked()" />
            <label for="slideOne"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

> RadioButton .css file:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}


.slideOne {
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 5px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideOne label {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideOne input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 37px;
}

.breakwordcont
{
    width:90%;
    font-size: 0.7em;

}

.desc {

    width:65px;
     height:30px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    margin-left:3px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
}

.control {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

**EDIT FOR FUTURE VIEWERS WITH THE SAME ISSUE**

---

based on @deek answer this are the relevant changes in my fixed code:
1. adding ID property to radioButton .ts file:

```
export class RadioButtonComponent
{
    @Input() ID: string;
// ... rest of class definitions...
}
```

2. Passing the ID for each radio button from the parent component:

   ```
     <div><MyRadBtn [ID]="'id-one'" [Description]="'Break Word'" [BackColor]="RadButtonBackColor">Loading...</MyRadBtn></div>
     <div><MyRadBtn [ID]="'id-two'" [Description]="'SQL Mode'"  [BackColor]="RadButtonBackColor">Loading...</MyRadBtn></div>
   ```
3. binding the id of the input to the css class:

   ```
    <div class="breakwordcont" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': BackColor}">
        <div class="desc"><span>{{Description}}</span></div>
        <div class="control">
            <div class="slideOne">
                <input type='checkbox' value='None' id={{ID}} name='check' />
                <label for={{ID}} (click)="clicked()"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:  input[type=checkbox]:checked + label

*only apply this rule if passed in ID matches clicked element.*

Your issue is the class and Id names of the input in Radio component.

When they are injected, your code has them both with the same id and class names.

You'll either need to make them into separate components with different CSS/IDs or take an input parameter to set class name and id depending on what css you want to apply. I suggest the latter.

You can probably just set to different ID depending on how your css is(I havent read it all).

```
<div><MyRadBtn [slideClass-ID]="id-one" [Description]="'Break Word'" [BackColor]="RadButtonBackColor">Loading...</MyRadBtn></div>
<div><MyRadBtn [slideClass-ID]="id-two" [Description]="'SQL Mode'" [BackColor]="RadButtonBackColor">Loading...</MyRadBtn></div>
```

then bind the id for the input to slideClass-ID.

Comment: thank you! it saved me a lot of time <sarcasm> so intuitive(-: </sarcasm>

Comment: Alternatively instead of passing the ID as a param you can generate the ID for every new instance of `RadioButtonComponent`